# Date value in Django API response is one day lesser that actual value in database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a Django model which contain a date field. While I am calling a get API to get values from this model. The date value in response is one day lesser that what is there in the db. Please find a sample table

| id | type | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test_type | 2019-05-23 05:30:00 |

While I calling a get API I got response like this:

```
{id":"1","type":"test_type","created_date":"2019-05-22T20:00:00-04:00"}
```

Can you please help to fix this issue. And please give me an idea why this is happening.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your timezone settings, both the database's and Django's; not only is the date "wrong", but the time is off too.

Comment: @AKX Thanks for the comment. While cheking my Django timezone and db time zone is different. Once I made them same the issue is resolved.